# What is the meaning of : "int i, (!!i)"?

Tags: c++

We have the following C++ code:

```
int i;
(!!i);
```

What is the operation on variable i?

Comment: it's "not not i". basically turning it into a 1 or 0.

Comment: @Marc B   i understand it is "not not i", but why 1 or 0? i has not been initialized yet.

Comment: `!!(non-zero) -> !!(true) -> !false -> true`. `!!(zero) -> !(true) -> false`. since false and true and generally #defined as 1 and 0...

Comment: @Marc B   I know it is "not not i", but how we know it is 1 or 0?  We have not yet initialized the variable.

Comment: @ChongZheng: unitialized variables can have any value. Applying the negation operator twice must result in either 1 or 0, regardless of the initial unknown value. If the unknown value is 0, the result will be 0. If the unknown value is non-zero, the result will be 1.

Comment: If it's uninitialized then this is undefined behavior.

Comment: You mean, the fact that `i` is uninitialized is on purpose? Or say, you know what `!!i` means for initalized variables, but not on uninitialized variables?

Comment: Can you make a MCCVE of the context you found it in? The statement has no effect, otherwise.

Comment: @ChongZheng  This won't cause anything anyway, the expression `(!!i)` is evaluated, but not used

Comment: @VittorioRomeo No, it's UB, period.

Comment: @T.C.  It is UB by the C-spec, which says every variable must be set before being used.   However, it is functional in every single C implementation I've ever seen or heard of, where uninitialized variables have unknown values (but values none-the-less)

Answer (score 6):

I've seen this done to prevent warnings about ***"Warning, variable i is unused"***.

After the odd `!!i` statement, the variable is now (technically) used in an expression, so the warning is suppressed, but it didn't actually change anything.

Example:

```
void MyFunc()
{
    int i;
    (!!i);       // Suppress the warning caused by the block below.
#if DEBUG        // In Retail / Non-Debug code, i is not used, and a warning is created!!
    i = GetCountOfSomething();
    printf("The count of something is %d\n", i);
#endif // DEBUG
}
```

Comment: Either way. Gotta say that if one chooses to do this, it's a really bad programming practice.

Comment: Yep. Some dev environments have warning levels which warn and abort the build for any usused variables, so might want to do this to say "don't bug me about this one" during development. For the ones I've seen though, you can also just do i = 0; (which probably wouldn't confuse anyone) Maybe some people just enjoy the drama of !!, but this question demonstrates it can be confusing when others read your code... @AlexandreSeverino Why would !! be "really bad" if it were commented as above?

Comment: @Dronz:  Initializing it to zero will not fix the problem I'm describing.   Then the variable is _initialized_, but it is still _not used_ in an expression.  The warning is about a variable that is not used.

(A separate warning might exist about an uninitialized variable.  But that is a different problem)

Comment: This seems much worse to me. Instead of an "unused variable" warning, you'll get a "use of uninitialized variable" warning and/or a "statement with no effect" warning, and you'll be invoking undefined behavior. What's the point of the `!!` anyway, why not just `i;`?

Comment: @abelenky Ok I thought I've seen some such warning that would let you go with int i; i = 0; . In the above case, putting i inside the DEBUG block would work. Seems like this only (in my cases so far) comes up when I'm just making a quick change to test something and don't want to rearrange the code and then have to change it back.

Comment: @Dronz:  Some older C compilers won't let you put variables inside a block.  All variables must be declared at the top of the function, no exceptions!  (this is rarely a requirement anymore... it would mean the compiler is pretty old)

Comment: @abelenky Ah! Ya I can see myself writing int Groan = 0; int i = 0; i += Groan;

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized variables in `c++` have undefined behavior. They allocate memory on the **stack** but do not clean it. Knowing that, `int i;` will have an unexpected value. You will have to initialize it eventually **before** manipulating it. I can't think of any practical use of working an uninitialized variable. For me it looks like a bad programming practice.

`(!!i)` won't do anything. `i` being initialized or not.

Comment: Yes, when I first time see the code, I don't understand why they want to apply "not not“ operation on the uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

The unary `operator!` is being applied twice to the `i` variable.
Equivalent to: `(!(!(i)))`

Applying the negation operator twice to an integer results in either `0` or `1`, depending on the original value of the variable.

- If `i` is `0`, then `!i` is `1`, therefore `!!i` is `!1`, which is `0`.
- If `i` is **non-zero**, then `!i` is `0`, therefore `!!i` is `!0`, which is `1`.

Comment: I guess the OP wants to know the motivation of doing that on an uninitialized variable, not what it's doing.

Comment: @black  Yes, when first time I see the code, I don't understand why they want to doing that on an uninitialized variable, but Stackoverflow website does not allow me to submit a question till I change it to this...